# git push to remote gives fast-forward error

Tags: git

I am trying to deploy to a remote server and this is the error I get -

```
git push uat release/1.1:release
To ubuntu@ubuntu-jvm:/repos/tms/uat
 ! [rejected]        release/1.1 -> release (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ubuntu@ubuntu-jvm:/repos/tms/uat'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details
```

When I try pulling from the remote this is the error I get:

```
git pull uat release:release/1.1
remote: Counting objects: 58, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (33/33), done.
remote: Total 35 (delta 17), reused 8 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (35/35), done.
From ubuntu-jvm:/repos/tms/uat
 ! [rejected]        release    -> release/1.1  (non-fast-forward)
```

I have a bare git repo at the remote location.

How do I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two repositories are out of sync. You will need to handle any merge conflicts on your local repository, and then push again.

```
git checkout release/1.1
git fetch --all
git merge origin/release
# resolve conflicts
git commit -av
git push
```